# why did this constructor chaining cause stack overflow(java)

Tags: java, constructor

So I have the code below but it caused java.lang.StackOverFlowError.
I guess maybe creating an new object inside the second constructor may 
have caused an infinite loop or something. But I don't fully understand
why this happened. Could someone explain it to me? I'd appreciate it!

```
private double x;
private double y;
private double z;
private double[] elements;
/**
 * Creates a 3D vector from an array
 * @param v array containing 3 components of the desired vector 
 */
public Vector3(double[] v) {
    this(v[0], v[1], v[2]);
}

/**
 * Creates a 3D vector from 3 numeric scalar components
 * @param x x coordinate
 * @param y y coordinate
 * @param z z coordinate
 */
public Vector3(double x, double y, double z) {
    this(new Vector3(x, y, z));
}

/**
 * Clones an existing vector
 * @param old an existing Vector3 object 
 */
public Vector3(Vector3 old) {
    x = old.x;
    y = old.y;
    z = old.z;
    elements = new double[3];
    elements[0] = x;
    elements[1] = y;
    elements[2] = z;
}
```

Comment: Constructing an instance to construct an instance is an odd thing to want to do anyway...

Comment: And why do you need `elements` as well as `x`, `y` and `z`?

Comment: Yeah I see that I can't call a constructor inside itself. I need x, y, z for an object called Vector. But now some of the answers really helped and now I know why I put it in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

```
public Vector3(double x, double y, double z) {
    this(new Vector3(x, y, z));
}
```

I'm not sure what you're up to do, but it seems you're calling the Vector3 constructor in itself. This is causing the infinite loop.

Comment: He tries to call the _copy constructor_ with that!

Comment: I know, but the copy constructor's argument is a call to the 3-parameter constructor again @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: You know? Ok, then I misunderstood your sentence "I'm not sure what you're up to do".

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I see how it works behind the code

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor

```
public Vector3(double x, double y, double z) {
    this(new Vector3(x, y, z));
}
```

you are calling the same constructor again and again (i.e. `new Vector3(x, y, z)`). That causes the SOE. This happens before the copy constructor with the call to `this(...)` even has a chance.

Assuming the following class

```
public class Vector3 {
    // No need for an array. Or if you want an array, discard the doubles.
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    public double getX() { return x; }
    public double getY() { return y; }
    public double getZ() { return z; }
}
```

the correct way to build up constructors is the following:

1) Start with a constructor that builds up a whole instance with all elementary data:

```
public Vector3(double x, double y, double z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}
```

2) If you want to add some other convenience constructors, do it his way:

```
public Vector3(double[] elements) {
    this(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2]);
}
```

3) A copy constructor can be handled the same way:

```
public Vector3(Vector3 origin) {
    this(origin.getX(), origin.getY(), origin.getZ());
}
```

All the other constructors can be built by calling the first constructor!

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah I was doing a constructor chaining and now I understood how to do it. I truly appreciate your answer, it's super helpful!